# How to resize UITableView inside a UIViewController

Tags: iphone

I have added a `UILabel` and `UITableView` inside a `UIViewController` using interface builder and sized the `tableView` below the label. I have also hooked the `UITableView` to a property but on running it on both device and simulator the `tableView` covers the entire `UIViewController` hiding the `UILabel`. Also I have checked the property is hooked up correctly because I am able to change the background color of the `UITableView` through it. 
Please anyone here can help me fix it.
Thanks

```
-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    self.pTableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 50, 320, 100);        // Doesn't work

    self.pTableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];       // Works
}
```

Comment: Try adding some debugging `NSLog` messages that print out the dimensions of the frame in both `viewWillAppear` and `viewDidAppear`.

Comment: You need to adjust the auto resizing mask of the table view appropriately.

Comment: Have you tried doing this in `viewDidLoad`?

Comment: Drewmm this is what i get // NSLog
self.pTableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 50, 320, 100);
viewWillAppear Table bounds - x: 0.000000 y: 0.000000 w: 320.000000 h: 100.000000
viewDidAppear Table bounds - x: 0.000000 y: 0.000000 w: 320.000000 h: 416.000000
Erway: i did try but it still takes the whole view              Mike: Could you please tell me what to turn off in auto resizing to keep it from taking the whole space

Comment: Nothing works. So deleted the tableview from the uiviewcontroller and added it programmatically and that works fine.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably happening because of Autolayout. If you have layout constraints configured in Storyboarding, views will not respond to changes to the frame property. You can disable Autolayout in your storyboarding file by unchecking the box that says "Use Autolayout" in File Inspector:

[image: File Inspector inside Interface Builder]